# Why does this question get a downvote? And how can I improve it?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, downvotes

I sometimes have a hard time asking questions on Stack Overflow. I did read the [how to ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) tutorial multiple times.

However, when I ask a question, I get a downvote without explanation. I don't really care about the downvote or reputation lost, but knowing *why* my question was downvoted would be really helpful for future questions.

Also, I'm scared of facing *the "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"* message again. I saw this when I was new to the site and had two questions with a score of −2 (and some without a vote).

I improved my questions after that and wasn't getting downvotes on them any more, but now, almost immediately after I ask a question, I get a downvote. I have waited for details on how to improve it, but no comment ever came.

So I was comparing [my most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501890/keep-footer-at-bottom-when-page-height-dynamically-changes-without-flexbox-or-j) to my previous upvoted questions, and I really don't understand why it was downvoted. I provided all the necessary content, I have a well-explained problem, I've shown what I've tried so far, I have a working "snippet", and I've explained what I can and cannot use.

The lack of an explanation brought me here. Can you guys help me improve my question?

---

### UPDATE

After a lot of feedback, in the comments and answers, I've improved the question in question. And received a lot of positive feedback.

So the question is not as it was anymore. For simplicity, I copied the original question and pasted it here. Alot of people are reading this topic, and this might help them to improve their questions.

> ### Keep footer at bottom when page height dynamically changes. Without flexbox or JavaScript
>
> There are alot of topics out there, giving solutions to keep the
>   footer at the bottom of a page. I am struggling however to get it
>   working.
>
> The problem is that the page can dynamically change its height.
>
> With the current solution im using, found **[here](https://chrisbracco.com/css-sticky-footer-effect/)**, the `footer` is at the
>   bottom of the page. But when the page height dynamically changes, the
>   `footer` remains at its exact `position`.
>
> **See snippet below for a visual demo (best used in full window mode)**
>
> ```html
> Go for snippet to the original question. I can't get it working inside the quote :(
> ```
>
> How can i let `css` know the height changed? And to keep that footer at
>   the `bottom` of the `document` instead that its staying at the `bottom` of
>   the `window`?
>
> I cannot use `flexbox` or `JavaScript`.
>
> ---
>
> **- Source: [Keep footer at bottom of page when page height dynamically changes using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501890/keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-when-page-height-dynamically-changes-using-css)**

---

I would also like to thank everyone for the feedback and effort to help me improve my questions, not only me, but also all those who read this topic.

Comment: The reason is posted in comment that your question's is possibility to be duplicate. May be that can be reason.

Comment: Perhaps, ive looked into that. But its a user with 19 reputation. So i dont think he downvoted it. It's also not even an duplicate. If he read both the questions he would have seen it. Its also not a reason to downvote if hes not sure is it?

Comment: Hmm may be someone else did that after reading that comment. You have got only one downvote. Someone did that with my questions in serial way.

Comment: There are two obvious problems with your question: (1) You use inline code formatting for things that are not actually code, which is an incorrect use of formatting and makes the question hard to read. (2) The important parts of your question (the code to reproduce the problem) are hidden by default.

Comment: It was before the `duplicate` mark and the comments

Comment: @CodyGray Allright, good points. I will remember this and improve that in the existing question. Thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate all the tips and help. Ive improved the question and will remember it for future questions.

Comment: BTW, that's a much better question than many we get. Thank you for the effort you put in (including the effort to ask here and incorporate feedback!)

Comment: I restrict myself to [Swift] tagged questions, so please note - it wasn't me. (1) It looks like the "meta effect" helped you, you now are +1 with 2 down votes. (2) The reason for my comment is this - while related, could it be that you are actually asking *two* questions? That's frowned upon. (I only clicked on your question after reading this in the comments from you: * It's also not even an duplicate. If he read both the questions he would have seen it.*)

Comment: Here’s my .02. I had the same problem starting off here but I began to arrange my questions appropriately. I briefly but clearly describe the problem. I explain how my code is currently working and describe how I want it to work. I then explain what I’ve tried and finally I clearly and succinctly ask my question. After I employed this strategy my downvotes dropped to nearly zero.

Comment: In the original version, you did not even ask a question at all. You've fixed that in the edited version when you added `How can I ...`.  I will typically down vote anything that does not ask a question.  Don't just state your problem, or imply the question.  Ask it outright.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First of all I wouldn't leave a comment like this:

> Read question please, its not a duplicate. I came with this solution using all those existing questions

You can be sure we can read, there is no need to question that, I find it borderline rude.

The fact that it is not a duplicate needs to be shown *by you* by including links to *all those existing questions* and how you applied the answers in your solution but still rendered a different result.

What might help is include that tiny bit of MCVE (the CSS rule) that you think is at the core of your problem, instead of relying on users to click open and run the Snippet.

Last but not least: Explain why you say *I cannot use flexbox or JavaScript.* while your MCVE does include jQuery/JavaScript. Or did you mean to say: I'm looking for an pure CSS answer.

Kudos for asking on Meta.

Comment: Thanks, im glad i asked here. This awnser helps me alot! I will remember for future questions, and improve the question in question.

Comment: "Question in question" gold

Comment: I think you're requesting mindreading when you ask for links to any question that any reader might think is a duplicate.  If someone mentions a possible duplicate in a comment, that's a good time to put into the question why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @WarrenDew I'm not requesting that, I use an hyperbole to make clear that it is impossible for us to know what the OP looked at if they don't even include *one* of the posts they claimed to have looked at. And I personally think you're too late if you hit an duplicate comment but if you're on top of the ball and are quick enough to explain why it doesn't match, that might work. Still risky, not great advice for new users I would say.

Comment: In reality, the workflow is usually that the question gets closed and then gets reposted discussing how it's different from the one that it was mistakenly marked a duplicate of, yes.

Answer (score 12):

I felt the temptation to downvote when I look at your original question in the edit history, and I think it comes down to the wording of the opening paragraph "*there are a lot of solutions out there*".

If there are "lots of solutions" then go and use one. If none of them solve the problem, they aren't solutions.

Something about it feels like: "*I want to read email. There are lots of email clients out there but I can't make any of them work. Make me a new email client*" - ha ha no, what are you so special? Go and make one of them work or make your own if you have to be so different and unique.

---

**That's not a correct reading of your question** - you have chosen one, you are trying to make one work, you do have a specific problem with it, you have specific questions and code - that's all good. But it's all *after* the impulse to downvote.

I can only guess, but if I felt the pull to downvote, others probably did, and I think this is why I did. Maybe rewriting it like:

> There are lots of approaches out there, [this one] looks the best and I'm trying to use it - but when the content dynamically changes size, the footer gets stuck in place - why? How can I tell the CSS to re-apply? Here's my code, etc ...

Your current edit (at the time of writing) is way better - lots of immediately visible code and samples makes it very clear up front that you're asking for help with implementation, not asking for yet another solution on a plate.

Comment: Good point of view. Thanks for pointing it out the way you see and read it. I really appreciate all the feedback you guys giving me! It helps me improve my questions